# В односвязном списке функция дублирования не работает для последнего элемента

Tags: c, visual-studio

Нужно дублировать элементы списка поле дата которых есть чётное число (дубликат вставить перед нужным элементом)Мне казалось что функция(copy) рабочая , но когда я изменил число элементов в списке я заметил что последний элемент списка не дублируется в том случае если количество элементов не четное , не понимаю почему это происходит

Изначально список состоит из 3 элементов :(2,3,4) после функции copy выходит :(2,2,3,4) а должно:(2,2,3,4,4)

Изменил функцию copy : добавил еще один указатель для анализа работы по tmp а не по tmp->next , но почему-то не работает ,думаю, что это может быть из-за того , что я не правильно использовал указатель back .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct TNode {
    int data;
    struct TNode *next;
};
typedef struct TNode Node;
void CreateNode(Node** head, int d)
{
    Node *tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->data = d;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}
void copy(Node** head)
{
    Node *tmp;
    Node *back;
    tmp = (*head);
    back = (*head);
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp = (*head) && tmp->data % 2 == 0)
        {
            Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            P1->data = (*head)->data;
            P1->next = (*head);
            (*head) = P1;
        }
        else if (tmp->data % 2 == 0)
        {
            Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            back->next = tmp;
            P1->data = back->next->data;
            P1->next = back->next;
            back->next = P1;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    Node *head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        CreateNode(&head, i + 2);
    }
    Node *tmp = head;
    /*copy(&head);
    while (tmp)
    {
        printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    copy(&head);
    Node *i = head;
    while (i)
    {
        printf("  %d\n", i->data);
        i = i->next;
    }
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример входных данных, данные которые возвращает ваша программа и данные которые вы ожидали увидеть. Для редактирования вопроса можете нажать на кнопку "Править" под ним и добавить примеры.

Comment: `if (tmp->next)` - проверяет, что это **не** последняя запись, по-этому всё и заканчивается. Работать надо не со следующей записью `tmp->next`, а с текущей `tmp`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Изначально список состоит из 3 элементов :(2,3,4) после функции copy выходит :(2,2,3,4) а должно:(2,2,3,4,4)

Comment: @AlexGlebe По условию моей задачи : мне нужно добавлять новый элемент конкретно перед тем ,что удовлетворяет условие ,поэтому я и анализирую по `tmp->next`, т.е. насколько я знаю , добавить элемент перед tmp не получиться (Возможно я вас не понял)

Comment: @AlexGlebe , вот если по-другому : к примеру `tmp` становиться перед последним элементом и проверка: Существует ли следующий элемент?-Да. Этот элемент чётный?-Да. После создается новый элемент теперь который уже будет предпоследним и он будет такой же как и последний. Как-то так я это вижу

Comment: @AlexGlebe , на cщет того что добавить новый элемент не получиться я имел введу , что не получиться в том случае , когда буду анализировать просто по `tmp`.

Comment: @SLARDAr15 вам перед каждый четным элементом нужно создать новый элемент с тем же значением? Если да, то вам нужно рассматривать `tmp`, т.к. если первый элемент четный, то вы его пропускаете, но вам нужно для добавления хранить указатель на предыдущий элемент.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Выходит без без дополнительного указателя не обойтись, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `if (tmp = (*head) && tmp->data % 2 == 0)` У вас опечатка, нужно использовать не знак присваивания, а сравнения `==`.
2. `back` это же предыдущий элемент относительно `tmp`, тогда его нужно обновлять также, как и `tmp`.

   ```
   back = tmp
   ```

   Обязательно перед `tmp = tmp->next`

И немного можно украсить код)

1. Во 2-ом `if` можно написать так:

   ```
   Node* P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   P1->data = tmp->data;
   P1->next = tmp;
   back->next = P1;
   ```

   Я думаю тут понятно, что `back->next = tmp` была лишней и можно  обращаться к `tmp`.
2. Можно заметить, что есть похожие строчки кода, по этому избавимся от них

   ```
   if (tmp->data % 2 == 0) {
       Node* P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
       P1->data = tmp->data;
       P1->next = tmp;
       if (tmp == (*head))
           (*head) = P1;
       else back->next = P1;
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно знак "=" никак не вписывается в if , не обратил внимание . Только не понял на счет 2. похожие строчки кода вы имеете введу `back->next = tmp` ? И я не понял что это за код (последний)?

Comment: И еще ,я в первом ответе просто изменил код , может мне нужно было его в конец добавлять с новой строки?

Comment: Если вы добавите все, что в первых двух пунктах написано и измените код во 2-ом `if`, как в ответе, то там сложно не заметить что 3 строчки повторяются чуть ли не 1 в 1. Насчет второго комментария не понял.

Comment: Код из пункта 2, это замена вашему `if...else`. Т.к. строчки повторяются. Например и там и там у вас  `Node* P1 = ...` и там и там `P1->data` и `P1->next`. Только в 1 случае `head` в другом `tmp`, но у вас же проверка `if(tmp == *head)` то есть можно `head` заменить на `tmp` и теперь у вас 3 строчки 1 в 1. А дальше если вы рассматриваете первый элемент, то `tmp == *head` и нужно вставить элемент в начало, а если `tmp != head` то `back->next = P1`. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Да , спасибо я понял , вы четко сделали 20 строчек кода в 9 я так пока не могу)

Comment: @SLARDAr15 пожалуйста выберите один из ответов, как "Правильный ответ", нажав на галочку слева от ответа :) Это нужно для того, чтобы другие пользователи, у которых может возникнуть похожая проблема, могли сразу смотреть принятый ответ, а не читать все (если им конечно не нужно это)

Answer (score 0):

Если вставлять дубликат не до, а после элемента с четными данными, то программа будет более элегантна
(кстати, в этом случае в функцию копирования можно передавать не указатель на голову списка, а сам голову (указатель на элемент списка)).

```
void copy(Node* head) 
{
  for (Node *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next)
    if (tmp->data % 2 == 0) {
       Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
       *p = *tmp; // да, структуры можно копировать, теперь p->next = tmp->next
       tmp->next = p;
       tmp = p;   // это для правильного перехода к следующему элементу
    }
}
```

Comment: `*p = *tmp;` не понял как тут происходит копирование , я это вижу как указатель на p становиться на место туда где же *tmp , я бы этого вообще не писал бы, возможно из-за моей некомпетентности

Comment: `*p` означает все содержимое (в зависимости от типа), на которое указывает указатель. Если у вас есть 2 структуры одного типа, например `struct s {int a, b, c} s1, s2;`, то вы можете написать `s1 = s2;` и компилятор осуществит копирование всех 3-х полей s2 в те же поля s1. Поэтому, имея указатели на s1 и s2, например, `struct s *sp1 = &s1, *sp2 = &s2;` можно написать то же самое, как `*sp1 = *sp2`. / Возможно, вы еще просто не дочитали K&R (или что вы читаете по языку Си) до этого места. / Да, осторожность не повредит и лучше писать то, что понимаешь. Тогда просто по полям скопируйте.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока-что даже ничего толком и не читал , только вот планирую начать

Comment: @SLARDAr15, как же вы программируете? Надо взять книжку, прочесть ее за 3 дня, пару недель порешать примеры из нее, ну, вот тогда можно и самому двигаться дальше

Comment: я просто пользуюсь тем что дает институт ну и интернет конечно же , но книгу прочитать нужно будет обязательно , мне кажется оно мне даст намного больше